# "keep an account" in a context. Confusion

Tags: word-usage

This is a TOEFL question.

A professor is lecturing about sociology. Well... there are 3 criteria according to the professor in order to make the social research "objective", which is, standardization, reliability, validity. When he further elaborates about the standardization, he is developing like below

> Let's take a look at standardization. If you were to ask a group of professionals working, say, in healthcare, **to keep an account** of a day at work, their accounts would probably differ **because people are usually subjective about what is important and what is not**. In order to avoid this type of bias...

In this case, googling does not help. Kindly take a look at the definition from a dictionary.

[image]

I think the definition "calculate" fits enough. However, what confuses me is the speech he give me after that.

> **because people are usually subjective about what is important and what is not**.

If the professor did not say the above, I completely understand what "to keep an account" means, because I guess it would mean **To calculate the hours of work at a day of professionals in healthcare**.

But his latter risen part, confuses me, since I can not relate the 2 contexts.

How **would you think** when these 2 contexts could be in harmony? (Please be reminded : no more context is available.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misinterpreted the sense of [account](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/account) that's being used:

> **7** : a description of facts, conditions, or events : report, narrative · the newspaper *account* of the fire · By all *accounts* they're well-off. ; also : performance · a straightforward *account* of the sonata

Asking them **to keep an account** of a day at work doesn't mean to *calculate* anything. It means to write down or recount what they did.

The fact that people's memories are subjective is related to, for example, witnesses to a crime giving different *accounts* of the events that transpired.